# Count changes in an array from x to x periods

Tags: python

I currently have the following function that counts the variations on an array with some specifications:

```
def count_pump_switches(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        if arr[i - 1] != arr[i] and arr[i] != 0 and i % 5 !=0:
            count += 1
    return count
```

My goal is to change it so that the output is a list that stores the count, for example, 5 to 5 indexes. For example in this array: [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], instead of the output being 2, it should be [1,1]

Comment: Can you add more examples? Are you just trying to remove zeroes from a list?

Comment: so in this example: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] the output should be [4,4] ?

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,,4], in this example there are 4 changes in the first 5 elements and 3 in the second 5, the current function would output: 7, what I want is for it to be [4,3]

Comment: yes @Ruan, but in this example, it doesn't account for variations to 0, so it would be [4,3], but the idea is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second loop level:

```
def count_pump_switches(arr):
    counts = []
    for n in range(0,len(arr), 5):
        count = 0
        for i in range(n+1, n+5):
            if i >= len(arr): break
            if arr[i - 1] != arr[i] and arr[i] != 0 and i % 5 !=0:
                count += 1
        counts.append(count)
    return counts
```

Demo:

```
>>> count_pump_switches([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1])
[1, 1]
>>> count_pump_switches([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
[4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this code works for you:

```
import math

def count_pump_switches(arr):
    changes = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        ci = math.floor(i/5)
        if (ci >= len(changes)):
            changes.append(0)
        if arr[i] != 0:
            changes[ci] += 1

    return changes
```